# Java Swing Timer

Tags: java, swing, timer

```
ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        //...Perform a task...

        logger.finest("Reading SMTP Info.");
    }
};
Timer timer = new Timer(100 ,taskPerformer);
timer.setRepeats(false);
timer.start();
```

According to the documentation this timer should fire once but it never fires.
I need it to fire once.

Answer (score 22):

This simple program works for me:

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception{
        ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                //...Perform a task...

                System.out.println("Reading SMTP Info.");
            }
        };
        Timer timer = new Timer(100 ,taskPerformer);
        timer.setRepeats(false);
        timer.start();

        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i found my problem logger is initialized after this code is run that's why i never saw my test messages. switching logger with println helped.

Comment: IIRC, you shouldn't use javax.swing.Timer off the EDT.

Comment: I think I love you right now! :D Thank you very much!

Comment: This answer suggests that the main thread was finishing before the timer finishes.  Since the main thread is special, all other non-daemon threads will also terminate when main() terminates.  To avoid this (without using daemon threads) you should get a reference to the timer thread, and in main() call `<timer thread object>.join();`

Answer (score 6):

This Program will work fine...

`setRepeats(boolean flag)` function used to set call the `function(actionPerformed)` repeatedly or only one time if

1. `timer.setRepeats(false) == timer` calls the actionperformed method for only one time
2. `timer.setRepeats(true) == timer` calls the actionPerformed method repeatedly based on specified time

**Swing Timer Work**

1. do the task one time
2. do the task repeated time

**steps to create swing timer:**

1. create the actionlistener
2. create the timer constructor then pass time and actionlistener in that
3. implement the `actionPerformed()` function in which do your task
4. use `timer.start()` for start the task between the time specified in timer constructor, use `timer.stop()` for stop the task

Example:

```
ActionListener al=new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        //do your task
        if(work done)
            timer.stop();//stop the task after do the work
    }
};
Timer timer=new Timer(1000,al);//create the timer which calls the actionperformed method for every 1000 millisecond(1 second=1000 millisecond)
timer.start();//start the task
```

Comment: hey your syntax is slightly wrong but I like the simple snippet
`ActionListener al=new ActionListener(){//code};` is correct instead of `ActionListener al=new ActionListener({//code});`

Answer (score 1):

Your task likely only needs to *report* results on the event thread (EDT) but do the actual work in a background thread at some periodic rate.

[ScheduledExecutorService](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) is *EXACTLY* what you want. Just remember to update the state of your UI on the EDT via SwingUtility.invokeLater(...)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing from the log statement that you're doing some sort of SMTP operation.  I think I'm right in saying the `java.swing.Timer` is intended for UI related timed operations, hence why it needs and EDT running.  For more general operations you should use `java.util.Timer`.

This article is linked from the JavaDocs - http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/timer/