# Updating a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, countdowntimer

I have a `JFrame` on which I want to simulate a countdown (like a rocket launch). So I set up the frame by hiding various controls (`setVisible(false)`) and displaying a `JLabel` with the text (this is the text that is supposed to countdown: 3, 2, 1, Go).

The text on that `JLabel` starts out at "3". My intent is to simply have the execution of the program wait for 1 second, then change the text to "2", wait another second, change to "1", etc.). At the end, I hide the `JLabel` and redisplay all of the controls and everything proceeds as normal.

What I am doing isn't working. It seems to wait for the correct amount of time, and when it is done, my JFrame looks great and works as intended. But during the 4 seconds of the countdown method, all I see is a white JFrame. Not the 3, 2, 1 that I want.

Here is my code. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

```
public void countdown() {
    long t0, t1;        

    myTest.hideTestButtons(true);
    myTest.repaint();

    t0 =  System.currentTimeMillis();
    do {
        t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    } while ( (t1 - t0) < 1000);

    myTest.TwoSeconds();
    myTest.repaint();
    t0 =  System.currentTimeMillis();
    do {
        t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    } while ( (t1 - t0) < 1000);


    myTest.OneSecond();
    myTest.repaint();
    t0 =  System.currentTimeMillis();
    do {
        t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    } while ( (t1 - t0) < 1000);


    myTest.Go();
    myTest.repaint();
    t0 =  System.currentTimeMillis();
    do {
        t1 = System.currentTimeMillis();
    } while ( (t1 - t0) < 1000);

    myTest.hideTestButtons(false);
    myTest.repaint();
}

public void TwoSeconds() {
    lblCountdown.setText("2");
}

public void OneSecond() {
    lblCountdown.setText("1");
}

public void Go() {
    lblCountdown.setText("Go!");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `Timer` instead. An active wait is in most of the cases highly discouraged.
Here is the type of code you'll need to integrate:

```
final Timer ti = new Timer(0, null);
ti.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    int countSeconds = 3;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(countSeconds == 0) {
            lblCountdown.setText("Go");
            ti.stop();
        } else {
            lblCountdown.setText(""+countSeconds);
            countSeconds--;
        }
    }
});
ti.setDelay(1000);
ti.start();
```

Comment: Thank you. I have some better code, but still can't get this to work. I marked your answer as the solution. Since my code is now totally different, I'll re-post rather than pollute this thread. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to use [javax.swing.Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) to do the timing on your application.

What's happening is that you're running everything on one thread - so the UI (which runs on a separate thread) doesn't have an opportunity to update.

If you want an example of how this works, you can look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1006640/1515592