# Using a swing timer in java

Tags: java, swing, timer

I have not been coding in java for long, a month at most, but I have coded in multiple other object oriented languages.

I am trying to use the swing timer included in java.swing.timer, and I read https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html to try and understand it.

I understand that with `timer = new Timer(speed, this)`, speed is how often the timer fires, but I do not understand what `this` means. Also, I know that `public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)` will execute every time the timer fires, but is there a way for me to use two timers in the same class?

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constructor you're invoking has this signature:

```
public Timer(int delay, ActionListener listener)
```

This means that, in the example, `this` refers to an instance of the [`ActionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) interface.

In your example, the class containing the timer code happens to implement `ActionListener`.  This is simply for the convenience of having a succinct example.

You can pass any instance of an `ActionListener` to your timer.  If you're using Java 8, this is very simple using [method references](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html).

```
public class TheExample
{
  public TheExample()
  {
    final Timer timerOne = new Timer(speedOne, this::timerOneMethod);
    final Timer timerTwo = new Timer(speedTwo, this::timerTwoMethod);
  }

  private void timerOneMethod(ActionEvent e)
  {
    // do something exciting
  }

  private void timerTwoMethod(ActionEvent e)
  {
    // do something else exciting
  }
}
```

If you're not using Java 8, the same thing can be achieved using [anonymous inner classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).  You can find an [example of this way here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1006640/1212960).

Comment: Nice example for method references there! +1 for that!

Comment: There is an error at 'this::timerOne'.  The error says "Syntax error on tokens, delete these tokens".  Do you know how to fix this?

Comment: @SAT: the above code is valid for Java 8 - are you using Java 8? (Also check that your IDE is configured to Java 8 for the language level).

Comment: Thank you, my IDE was not using java 8, but I compiled it and ran it through the terminal and it worked properly. Also, in my Java textbook, there is an example where in main, 'className inst = new className();' is declared, and timer is declared as 'Timer clock = new Timer (speed, inst);'.  My question is, can I do something like this but with 'Timer clock = new Timer (speed, inst.func());'? Would this execute func() every time the timer fires?

Comment: @SAT you just need to satisfy the visibility rules - as the code is written above, the methods are `private` so can't be referenced external to the class.  If they were public, they could.  (As to whether that's good OO design, that's another thing ...)

Answer (score 2):

The javadoc for Timer tells you what that constructor is [about](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#Timer(int,%20java.awt.event.ActionListener)) - it takes an int and an instance of *ActionListener*.

So, to answer your first question, in the example code from Oracle, `timer = new Timer(speed, this)` happens within the *init* method of that Applet that makes up the example UI thingy. Thus: *this* refers to the "current" object (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3728062/what-is-the-meaning-of-this-in-java) for more details), being that Applet object the whole method "belongs" to.

And that only works because that example class TumleItem is declared as 
`TumbleItem extends JApplet implements ActionListener`.

For the record: understanding what *this* is about is absolutely basic stuff. If you don't know what *this* is about, then you shouldn't be engaging in UI coding yet. Learn to crawl before you try to run.

For your second question: for each instance of a Timer you want to use, you need an ActionListener that you can pass in. The old-school way of doing that would be to use anonymous inner classes, like

```
timer = new Timer(someSpeed, new ActionListiner() {
   @Override
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
      System.out.println("Whatever");
   }
}
```

Finally: that one example from Oracle is using Applets, and simply spoken: Applets are dead technology. Don't get too hung up on them; you better avoid spending time on those completely.